# Who can tell what the mistake is?

Tags: npm, sass

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at validateString (node:internal/validators:120:11)
    at Object.extname (node:path:837:5)
    at getOptions (C:\Users\skh43\Desktop\Тест сайт\node_modules\node-sass\bin\node-sass:228:40)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\skh43\Desktop\Тест сайт\node_modules\node-sass\bin\node-sass:408:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
PS C:\Users\skh43\Desktop\Тест сайт>
```

It says that the path should be a string, but no matter how much I try, I can't get it

Here is the file I was running

```
{
    "name": "test_site",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "scss": "node-sass -watch scss -o css"
    },
    "author": "me",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
        "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
    }
}
```

*I do not know what details I can add to the question so that it consists not only of code, but the site requires more text from me*

Comment: Well, you seem to be missing a `path` attribute in the file you are running

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do? What debugger are you using?

Comment: @mab0189 I wanted to work with sass and found a compiler on the Internet, as a result, I need a compiler from sass to css, I did everything, but when I run it, it gives this error, I ran everything through cmd